# Best way/How to pass Android ImageProxy reference to another activity

Tags: java, android

i am looking for a solution to send a Reference of an ImageProxy (bc i don´t want to save the Image right away-> ML-purpose) to another activity in Android.

My code in the sending activity looks like that:

```
    imageCapture.takePicture(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureSuccess(@NonNull ImageProxy image) {
            super.onCaptureSuccess(image);
            Intent sendImageResult = new Intent();
            
            // Magic


            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, sendImageResult);
            finish();
            image.close();
        }
```

My problem:

- is it the best way to save the image to a file and then send the content id?
- is there a way to get to the "buffer"-reference of the ImageProxy image?
- is there another best practice i just don´t know about?

My level is hobbyist!

Thank you!

Comment: "is there another best practice i just don´t know about?" -- use one activity instead of two. Use fragments or composables to allow that one activity to display multiple screens.

Comment: As @CommonsWare said, you can use fragments. I can give u an answer if you want to go with fragments. But, before that i'd like you to know a bit about fragments from [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I didn’t know about fragments. How can I do it with a fragment ?